# Store shell arguments in file while preserving quoting

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sh

How can shell arguments be stored in a file for later use while preserving quoting?

To be clear: I don't want to pass on the arguments in place, which could be easily done using `"$@"`. But actually *need* to store them in a file for *later* use.

```
#!/bin/sh
storeargs() {
    : #-)
}
if "$1"
then
    # useargs is actuall 'git filter-branch'
    useargs "$@"
    storeargs "$@"
else
    # without args use those from previous invocation
    eval useargs $(cat store)
fi
```

.

```
$ foo 'a "b"' "c 'd'" '\'' 'd
e'
$ foo # behave as if called with same arguments again
```

The question likely comes down to how to quote a string using *common* tools in general (awk, perl, ...). I would prefer a solution that does not make the quoted string unreadable. The content of `store` should look more or less like what I would specify on the commandline.

The question is complicated by the fact that the arguments/strings to be quoted might already contain any kind of valid (shell) quoting and/or any kind of (significant) whitespace, so unconditionally putting single or double quotes around every argument or storing one argument per line won't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do the heavy lifting?

```
storeargs() {
     while [ $# -gt 0 ]
     do 
         printf "%q " "$1"
         shift
     done   
}
```

You can now

```
storeargs "some" "weird $1 \`bunch\` of" params >  myparams.txt
storeargs "some" 'weird $1 \`bunch\` of' params >> myparams.txt
cat myparams.txt
```

Output

```
some weird\ \ \`bunch\`\ of params
some weird\ \$1\ \\\`bunch\\\`\ of params
```

Comment: Hmmm.  %q is very nice, but only works with the bash builtin printf.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me.  Still, a solution that does not require bash would be even nicer.  Also the output does not look to nice, but that's okay. The $'...' kind of quoting it produces is new to me.

Answer (score 1):

This version stores the arguments one per line, so may be a bit ugly in terms of storage.  I doubt that it is completely robust, but it satisfies your example (for useargs() { for i in "$@"; do echo $i; done; } ):

```
storeargs() { printf "%q\n" "$@"; } > store

if test -n "$1"; then
  useargs "$@"
  storeargs "$@"
else
  eval useargs $args
fi
```

--EDIT--
Use %q in printf to quote the strings (shamelessly copied from sehe's answer).  Note that %q is available in the bash built-in printf, but not in standard printf.

Comment: so close... Depending on how it's used you'll get unintended variable, bracket expansion, process subsitution, redirection. If it's not eval-ed but simple read in a `while read` like you say, I think the worst that'll happen is that filenames containing newlines are no longer handled

Comment: newlines are definitely a problem.  Your solution with %q is good...I shall poach it.

Comment: +1 for avoiding loop - I went to the bash manpage to find out why single `%q` is fine: *The  format [in `printf`] is reused as necessary to consume all of the arguments.*